# Evaluating $\int\frac{4x^3-3x^2+6x-27}{x^4+9x^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\int\frac{4x^3-3x^2+6x-27}{x^4+9x^2}dx$$

this integral get very messy. Can I get a step by step breakdown of solving?

Comment: Whenever you get a ratio of polynomials to integrate, after long division if possible, break it up using partial fractions...

Comment: This is the third post in a time interval of less than ten minutes to use the exact words, "This integral gets very messy. Can I get a step by step break down ...". Each post by an (allegedly) different new user. What's the real story?

Answer (score 6):

> *No Step by step solution, but just a hint*

By reducing to partial fractions we get
$$\frac{4x^3-3x^2+6x-27}{x^4+9x^2}=\frac{Ax+ B}{x^2+9}+\frac{C}{x^2}+\frac Dx$$
$$Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx^2+9C+Dx^3+9Dx=4x^3-3x^2+6x-27$$
$$9C=-27\implies C=-3$$
$$9D=6\implies D=\frac23$$
$$A+D=4\implies A=-\frac{10}{3}$$
$$B+C=-3\implies B=0$$

> $$\frac{4x^3-3x^2+6x-27}{x^4+9x^2} =\frac{10x}{3(x^2+9)}-\frac{3}{x^2}+\frac{2}{3x}$$

Comment: shouldn't it be $\frac{Ax+B}{x^2+9}$?

Comment: A "thank you" would have sufficed. Don't be passive aggressive.

Answer (score 3):

Doing long division, I get $$\int{\frac{4}{x}-\frac{3}{x^2}-\frac{30}{x^3+9x}dx}$$ We can rewrite as $$\int{4x^{-1}-3x^{-2}-30(x^3+9x)^{-1}}$$

Comment: You'll again need to reduce last term to make integration easier!

Comment: @Integrator Honestly, I don't see a way to reduce the last term.

Comment: Can you please show me your steps from $\frac{30}{x^3+9x}$ to $\frac{10}{3x}-\frac{10x}{3(x^2+9)}$?

Comment: @Integrator but I got $\frac{30}{x^3+9x}$, not $\frac{30}{x^3+3x}$

Comment: Uhh... Let $$\frac{30}{x^3+9x}=\frac{A}{x}+\frac{Bx}{x^2+9}$$
Then $$Ax^2+9A+Bx^2=30$$
$$9A=30\implies A=\frac{10}{3}$$
$$A+B=0\implies B=-\frac{10}{3}$$
Hence
$$\frac{30}{x^3+9x}=\frac{10}{3x}-\frac{10x}{3(x^2+9)}$$ No w fine?

Comment: @Integrator pretty much yeah.